# How can I convert a Saxon XdmNode to an XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, saxon

I have a fully populated XdmNode and need to create an XmlDocument from it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the `XdmNode` is already a wrapper for an `XmlDocument`, in which case you can dive down through the wrappers to extract the underlying XmlDocument using `XdmNode.getUnderlyingXmlNode()`.

On the other hand, in the general case, you will need to copy the data across. The easiest way to do this is probably to run the XQuery "." using `XQueryEvaluator.Run()` with a `DomDestination` as the supplied `XmlDestination`; on completion, `DomDestination.XmlDocument` gives you the DOM document node.

If you're constructing the tree using an XSLT transformation or XSD validation, then you can supply a `DomDestination` as the output for that process, in which case you can avoid the copying process.